# JavaScript - Open a popup window and wait for it to be closed

Tags: javascript, popupwindow

I'm implementing Google OAuth2 authentication flow by generating the auth URL on my backend, opening it up as a popup window on my frontend, and then letting the backend do its thing once the user has auth'd inside of the popup window.

I'm looking for a way to know when the popup was closed by the user.

This is the flow I have in mind:

- user clicks the login button
- a popup opens with Google auth URL
- the user selects and account & logs in
- the popup is closed and the frontend detects it, and proceeds with the application flow

I don't know how to await the closure of this external window. I know it's possible because Google `gapi` client does it, but unfortunately the source code for that project isn't public.

This is how I'm opening the popup:

```
async logIn() {
    const url = await this.getAuthUrl(); // request url from backend
    window.open(url, "", "popup=true"); // open popup using that url
}
```

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
async logIn() {
    const url = await this.getAuthUrl(); // request url from backend
    await openPopup(url)
    // continue with application flow
}
```

How do you implement this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand from your description, google closes the authentication window itself. In this case, you can use setInterval

```
async logIn() {
  const url = await this.getAuthUrl(); // request url from backend
  const authPopup = window.open(url, "", "popup=true"); // open popup using that url
  const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    if (authPopup?.closed) {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
      // continue with application flow
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Your `logIn` function returns as soon as the interval is set but the asker wanted the code to await this function.